# How to create a Meeting Request using C# TimeZoneInfo class with the 4.6.5 Time Zone Component VTIMEZONE

Tags: c#, asp.net, timezone, timezone-offset

Good Day!

I am trying to update some pre-existing code that uses the 4.6.5 Time Zone Component VTIMEZONE to create a meeting request based on input from the user in a form on an asp.net website. The update I am making is removing the static list of timezones, which were listed as an enum, and replaced them with the TimeZoneInfo GetSystemTimeZones method. The problem is that the way the VTIMEZONEis set up has static values. I am wondering how best to approach this and would welcome any suggestions.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
        private const string vTimeZoneTemplate = @"
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Pacific
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20071104T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
TZOFFSETFROM:-0700
TZOFFSETTO:-0800
TZNAME:PST
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20070311T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:-0800
TZOFFSETTO:-0700
TZNAME:PDT
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Eastern
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20071104T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
TZNAME:EST
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20070311T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
TZNAME:EDT
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE";
```

The ultimate goal is to have the start time for the meeting request set for the selected timezone. i.e. I choose a 2 hour meeting in (UTC+02:00) Istanbul starting at 4:00 PM, it will create a meeting request from 4:00 PM to 6:00 PM in Istanbul Time, which is currently Turkey Standard Time.

if it helps, i am using TimeZoneInfo as such:

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> TimeZoneList = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
        this.ddlTimezones.DataSource = TimeZoneList;
        this.ddlTimezones.DataTextField = "DisplayName";
        this.ddlTimezones.DataValueField = "Id";
        this.ddlTimezones.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
//This string is used for timezones that observe DST
//RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=[Week of Month][Day];BYMONTH=[Month]
    private const string vTimeZoneTemplate1 = @"
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:{0}
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:{1}
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY={9}{11};BYMONTH={7}
TZOFFSETFROM:{2}
TZOFFSETTO:{3}
TZNAME:{4}
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:{6}
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY={10}{12};BYMONTH={8}
TZOFFSETFROM:{3}
TZOFFSETTO:{2}
TZNAME:{5}
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE";

//This string is used for timezones that do not observe DST; however, DAYLIGHT and STANDARD are required.
//Therefore used static dates and made no change to the UTCOffset
    private const string vTimeZoneTemplate2 = @"
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:{0}
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20070311T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:{1}
TZOFFSETTO:{1}
TZNAME:{2}
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20071104T020000
RRULE:RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
TZOFFSETFROM:{1}
TZOFFSETTO:{1}
TZNAME:{2}
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE";
```

and this:

```
         /**
         * get the adjustment rules for the selected timezone.
         * the adjustment rule is the Daylight Savings adjustment by default.
         * using the i to note the most recent rule.
         * DateStart and .DateEnd designate the begin and end of the rule.
         * DaylightTransitionStart and End designate the begin and end date of DST.
         * DayLightDelta is the difference between base UTC and the offset by DS, add to get DS value from Base.
         **/
        if (timezone.SupportsDaylightSavingTime)
        {
            TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule[] adjustments = timezone.GetAdjustmentRules();
            int i = adjustments.Length - 1;

            string body = string.Format(vTimeZoneTemplate1
                , timezone.Id
                , adjustments[i].DateStart.ToString(DateTimeFormat)
                , timezone.BaseUtcOffset
                , adjustments[i].DaylightDelta.Add(timezone.BaseUtcOffset)
                , timezone.DaylightName
                , timezone.StandardName
                , adjustments[i].DateEnd.ToString(DateTimeFormat)
                , adjustments[i].DaylightTransitionStart.Month.ToString("MM")
                , adjustments[i].DaylightTransitionEnd.Month.ToString("MM")
                , adjustments[i].DaylightTransitionStart.Week.ToString()
                , adjustments[i].DaylightTransitionEnd.Week.ToString()
                , adjustments[i].DaylightTransitionStart.IsFixedDateRule
                    ? adjustments[i].DaylightTransitionStart.Day.ToString().Substring(0, 2) 
                    : adjustments[i].DaylightTransitionStart.DayOfWeek.ToString().Substring(0, 2)
                , adjustments[i].DaylightTransitionEnd.IsFixedDateRule
                    ? adjustments[i].DaylightTransitionEnd.Day.ToString().Substring(0, 2)
                    : adjustments[i].DaylightTransitionEnd.DayOfWeek.ToString().Substring(0, 2)) +
                string.Format(vEventTemplate
                    , timezone.Id
                    , startDate
                    , endDate
                    , summary
                    , description
                    , Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                    , sequence
                    , DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormat)
                    , vCalAttendees.ToString()
                    , organizer.FullName
                    , organizer.Email
                    , location
                    , string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.DescriptionHtml) ? string.Empty : string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", Email.WrapHTMLBody(this.DescriptionHtml, false, false))) +
                (enableReminder ? vAlarmTemplate : string.Empty);

            return string.Format(baseVCalTemplate, body);
        }
        else
        {
            string body = string.Format(vTimeZoneTemplate2
                , timezone.Id
                , timezone.BaseUtcOffset
                , timezone.DisplayName) +
                string.Format(vEventTemplate
                    , timezone.Id
                    , startDate
                    , endDate
                    , summary
                    , description
                    , Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                    , sequence
                    , DateTime.Now.ToString(DateTimeFormat)
                    , vCalAttendees.ToString()
                    , organizer.FullName
                    , organizer.Email
                    , location
                    , string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.DescriptionHtml) ? string.Empty : string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", Email.WrapHTMLBody(this.DescriptionHtml, false, false))) +
                (enableReminder ? vAlarmTemplate : string.Empty);

            return string.Format(baseVCalTemplate, body);
        }
    }
```

worked for me. So, I hope it helps someone else out there as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

For current information String.Format and fields of TimeZoneInfo like [BaseUtcOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.baseutcoffset.aspx) should help with some properties

```
vTimeZoneTemplate =   String.Format(
     "BEGIN:VTIMEZONE\n...{0}{1}...",
      tz.BaseUtcOffset.Hours, tz.BaseUtcOffset.Minutes);
```

But I'm not sure if you can collect enough information with TimeZoneInfo to construct complete VTIMEZONE structure.

Comment: Because I don't know if you can - never did it myself/looked deep enough.